# Not clickable text input fields in web form in Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, gwt

I have a gwt application that shows a login form. 
I cannot click input fields using Android Chrome. I can do it using the default android browser and desktop browsers though.

```
<html><head>
  ...
<body >
<div >
    ...
</div>
<div id="main-header" >

   <div class="header down">
       <div class="face1"> 
          <div class="logo" debugid="header_logo" style="background-image: url(&quot;/logo_main.png&quot;);">
          </div> 
       </div>
       <div class="face2"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div >
    <div id="container" class="box">

      <form action="check" class="loginForm" method="POST"><div></div> 
         <input name="username" type="text"> 
         <input name="password" type="password"> 
         <input name="_spring_security_remember_me" type="checkbox" value="yes"> 
         <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="a.nocache.js"></script>


    <iframe src='javascript:""' 
           id="a" tabindex="-1" 
           style="position: absolute; width: 0px; height: 0px; border: none; left: -1000px; top: -1000px;"></iframe>
    <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I checked that there is no overlapping of elements. I added a listener for a click on the events like

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    console.log(evt);
 });
```

Logging shows text fields receive click events but continue to stay unfocused.
I check focus events like that:

```
document.getElementsByName("username")[0].addEventListener("focus",         function(evt) {
    console.log("username focus " + evt);
});
```

I don't receive focus events using android Chrome. But receive them using desktop Chrome.

I also cannot resize or scroll the page using android Chrome.

I can hack the bug by using such js script:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
    console.log(evt.target.focus());
 });
```

But I cannot figure out what is causing the problem. I cannot find any confirmed bugs in Chrome or GWT. What should I look for?

Android Chrome version: 47.0.2526.83

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "touchend" instead of "click" like:

```
document.addEventListener("touchend", function(evt){
```